# CTE with CASE statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying a query like this;

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
       ID, NAME, DEPT,
       CASE WHEN Fixed = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END,   
       CASE WHEN NotFixed = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END,
)
```

When I try to execute this query, I'm getting error like

> No Column was specified for column 4 of CTE

What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message: You forgot to give your calculated columns a name. This goes for both column 4 and column 5. So change your query to something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
       ID, NAME, DEPT,
       CASE WHEN Fixed = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS [Expr1],   
       CASE WHEN NotFixed = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS [Expr2],
    . . .
)
```

Feel free to change [Expr1] and [Expr2] to something more meaningful...

Comment: This looks like a different problem. Could you start a new question or edit your original question, with more details?